# Initial Conditions for the Three-Body Problem (Python code used)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, computational-physics, three-body-problem

I am currently doing a computational model of the three-body problem for an undergraduate computational physics class. The three bodies all have masses equal to one and G is also equal to one. There are 12 variables total (x1, y1, vx1, vy1, x2, y2, vx2, vy2, x3, y3, vx3, vy3 = z). There are likewise 12 initial conditions (z_0 = [x1_0, y1_0, vx1_0, vy1_0, x2_0, y2_0, vx2_0, vy2_0, x3_0, y3_0, vx3_0, vy3_0]).

Now, I need to know how to set the initial conditions so that in one case we get periodic orbits and in another case we get chaotic behavior that can be modeled by the Lyapunov exponent.

Here are some initial conditions that lead to chaos, but not in any predictable way that I can think of modeling with a Lyapunov exponent:

x1_0 = 0  #initial x-position of Mass 1

y1_0 = 0  #initial y-position of Mass 1

vx1_0 = 0  #initial x-velocity of Mass 1

vy1_0 = 0.5  #initial y-velocity of Mass 1

x2_0 = 1  #initial x-position of Mass 2

y2_0 = 1 #initial y-position of Mass 2

vx2_0 = 0  #initial x-velocity of Mass 2

vy2_0 = 0.25 #initial y_velocity of Mass 2

x3_0 = 0  #initial x-position of Mass 3

y3_0 = -1 #initial y-position of Mass 3

vx3_0 = 0  #initial x-velocity of Mass 3

vy3_0 = -1  #initial y-velocity of Mass 3

I have not yet determined any initial conditions that lead to periodic orbit. Please advise!

Comment: It may be debatable, but I think "x1, y1, z1 = 0, 0, 0" is more pythonic as it sets the state of particle 1 in one line, while your code spreads it out like some Matlab script.

Comment: I believe to have read that the three body problem does not have "stable" chaotic orbits. It's either stable and well behaved or it ejects one of the bodies (probably in fairly short order). My guess would be that it's not a particularly good system to study Lyapunov exponents on. For sanity's sake you may want to look at the existing literature about the three body problem before embarking on a project like that. Non-linear pendulums are much better behaved since they can't eject their moving bodies.